# Tried updating conda but got an error Cannot link a source that does not exist

Tags: anaconda, conda

I've tried updating conda using the command `conda updade conda` but I get an error:

```
ERROR conda.core.link:_execute_actions(337): An error occurred while installing package 'defaults::tqdm-4.42.1-py_0'.
CondaError: Cannot link a source that does not exist. C:\Users\User\Anaconda3\Scripts\conda.exe
Running `conda clean --packages` may resolve your problem.
Attempting to roll back.


CondaError: Cannot link a source that does not exist. C:\Users\User\Anaconda3\Scripts\conda.exe
Running `conda clean --packages` may resolve your problem.
```

Comment: And this still occurs after running `conda clean --packages` first?

Comment: I've already solved it, I updated tqdm

Answer (score 3):

What Joana Santos seems to mean by her comment is: installing "tqdm/tqdm: A Fast, Extensible Progress Bar for Python" fixes the problem for some 4.x versions (discussion can be found [here](https://community.intel.com/t5/Intel-Distribution-for-Python/Conda-update-Conda-fails/td-p/1126174)). Update it or try this if you don't have it:

```
conda install tqdm -f
```

And now this should work:

```
conda update conda
```